# Elasticsearch replica update mechanism

Tags: elasticsearch, replication

I want to know how replicas get updated in Elasticsearch 5 when new data is added to an existing index. Does it follow active replication or passive by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive replication: "Any newly indexed document will first be stored on a primary shard, and then copied in parallel to the associated replica shard(s)."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_failover.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html should make that a lot clearer.